# Groups of order $p^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I'm doing a past midterm and have no clue how to solve this problem

Let $p$ be a prime, $k \geq 1$, and $P$ a group of order $p^k$ :

1) Consider the action of $P$ on itself by conjugation. Show that the set of fixed points is equal to the center $Z(P) = \{x \in P : xy = yx \textrm{ for all } y \in P\}$.

2) Consider a composition series of $P$. Determine the center of the composition factors.

Comment: @Qeew21: The composition factors are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$, that is, they are abelian and so identical with their centers.

Comment: @tortoise: Are you sure that the composition factors are isomorphic to Z/pZ ? What about the composition series $\{ e, P\}$ with $k> 1$

Comment: @MarwanB: You are right! I forgot the case when $P$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3):

For the first one the fixed points of $P$ are all the $x\in P$ such that $gxg^{-1} = x$ for every $g\in P$, that is all the elements that satisfy $gx = xg$ so it's the center of $P$.